# Kohana 3.1.4 проблема с роутингом загружается только стартовая страница?

Tags: .htaccess, kohana

Появилась проблема с роутингом проекта на хостинге.

**Хостинг** - Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server 
папка с проектом - html/bdpn/ajax-new/old-php-layer/

Проект на Kohana 3.1.4 , при запуске проекта работает только роут default, при обращении к остальным путям они не отображаются, появляется сообщение The requested URL /html/bdpn/ajax-new/old-php-layer/test was not found on this server
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема? Такой же проект разместил на другом хостинге там пути работают (с поправкой на то, что я изменил base_url и в RewriteRule прописал другой путь ), у меня есть подозрение что необходима дополнительная настройка в файле .htaccess либо в настройках php сервера.

Comment: текстовой информацией гораздо продуктивнее делиться в виде текста, а не в виде картинки. замените, пожалуйста, картинки на текст, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

В роуте нужно указывать не название экшина а суть построения ссылки, что вы будите вводить только action без контроллера. А в defaults указываете контроллер с которым работаете, и нужно указать массив допустимых экшинов.

```
Route::set('auth', '<action>',array('action'=>'(login|logout)'))
        ->defaults(array(
            'controller' => 'Auth',
));
```

Правда так в версии 3.3 работает, не уверен что в 3.1 это так же.